# Linux distro advice

Tags: ubuntu-netbook

I'd like you to help me in choice of best linux distro for a netbook AcerAspireOne D255 with 1GB ram (physically increased to 1.5)...

I've tried Linux Mint 10, but it hasn't any support (for instance, no access to the App Manager) 
I've tried Xubuntu 13.04 but it freezes

It got to be a simple and easy to use one, though it will be installed on my father's pc but no problem for any installation type (graphic or key) for that i'm doing it myself.

Thank you for your advices

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Since this is very broad, and a request for opinions, you would probably be better off asking this on a forum ([we're different from a forum](http://askubuntu.com/about)), preferably one whose scope is broader than just Ubuntu (since you are considering some OSes besides Ubuntu. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an Asus Eee PC R051BX which is a tad slower than your netbook. I have been running every buntu taste to find out how well it works.

Ubuntu runs OK but choose only ubuntu 12.04 LTS with unity-2D (unity2Dis less demanding on CPU and battery). It is a tad slow during boot (though less than a minute) or starting programs (less than 10 seconds) but perfectly workable. It is a little bit faster than windows 7 on this machine.

Lubuntu is extremely fast on this machine and works like a charm. This is something you might try. It is easy to customise by you (not by your father) but it lacks the polish and shine of the other.

Both distro's are stable enough and I can't remember when an update left me a broken system.

You might try SuSE since it is known as the one of the better configured KDE desktop distro's. I persume this will run OK on that machine but I did not test it.

Answer (score 1):

i saw some other people looking for a leightweight ubuntu. maybe this is a solution for you :

[Lubuntu](http://www.lubuntu.net/)